# Disinheriting(?) / overriding .ToString to access COM Object .toString

Tags: java, .net, com, tostring

I have a java library that I am accessing in VB.NET via COM.  The objects on the java side expose non-trivial .toString methods that I need for debugging.  Unfortunately, when I call .toString on the COM objects, the call is being intercepted by the Object class' .ToString function.

How do I force the call to the COM-side .toString and prevent Object.ToString from firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the IDL for the java object?
Are you generating the runtime callable wrapper for the COM object?

I think you should change the interop assembly or manually generate the wrapper to change the toString() method to toStringJava() or to_String() or something else that doesn't clash with the syntax for object.ToString(). [Here's a starting point on MSDN for customizing runtime callable wrappers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e753eftz.aspx)

Comment: I think you may have lead me down the right path on this.  There is no IDL for the object and I don't have access to the source code.  I suspect that in order to do this, I would have to create the IDL/RCW manually and then alias it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8fbsf00.aspx

Comment: That's all I was trying to do. Glad it helped.